# VideoJS live RTMP stream take snapshot

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, video.js

I am developing an application with several live streams from Axis cameras watching a remote plant delivering FLV streams. The application connects to the cameras through **crtmpserver** and Apache **httpd** running on FreeBSD. I tried several open-source javascript players and video.js 5 seems to give best results being very flexible and well documented.

I was successful to do different 'tricks' with the cameras (like zooming and cropping parts of the video) and now I need to add the ability to take a **snapshot** from the video on a button activation.

I know that it is (probably) necessary to modify the **video-js.swf** file from the VideoJS distribution to get access to the flash stage. Unfortunately, my ActionScript knowledge is very weak.

Does anybody know where and how to start? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: **video-js.swf** is the final compiled/packaged app (much like say **.exe** or **.apk** compiled file formats). To edit any features you must edit the **.as** files, which have the actionscript code that makes SWF and re-compile with Flash (or a tool like Haxe). I dont use Video-JS so dunno if those AS files are downloadable (or whether the contents will mean anything to you).

Comment: Just for the challenge I'll do a basic test if you can provide a working RTMP test link to see if Flash can be made to draw the image (its normally not possible since RTMP is content-protected but there's a Flash trick I just remembered, it worked on another "not possible to snapshot" Flash playback method so it might work here too).

Comment: @VC One Just FYI, the **video-js.swf** source is available at https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf

Comment: Ok I see it, lemme read through it to see which as file you gotta edit. Do you have a sample RTMP link of your Plant's camera stream (if private please provide another known working one)

Comment: It's **[this AS file](https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf/blob/master/src/com/videojs/providers/RTMPVideoProvider.as)** you have to edit for RTMP streams but I would first try go straight for the **[videoJS.as](https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf/blob/master/src/VideoJS.as)**. In there is the line `addChild(_app);` which adds player to the Stage (as a displayObject). Look up tutorials on how to draw a displayObject to a bitmap then when that "security error" comes up I'll point you to the by-pass trick (untested though cos no link). Later you'll compile your own custom SWF

Comment: PS: since you'd be editing & compiling AS3 code, might as well make your own simple RTMP video player  (one **.as** file that just makes a video object, loads link & draws snapshot) That VideoJS has a lot of stuff going on you dont need and data is passed around different **.as** files so it'll be confusing for a beginner but my other advice stands if you still  choose to edit this VideoJS instead.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll start with **videoJS.as** & in case of problems I post another comment.

Comment: The task has been solved! I really met a strong "security error" problem that was caused by the **crtmpserver** (cf. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/c-rtmp-server ). Thanks @VC One.

Comment: Any comprehensive solutions for this?